# jQuery Sortable not working on nested link

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable, drag

I'm using Bootstrap Tab and applying the Drag effect of [jQuery Sortable](http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/). So far it's working fine on the first level including the Bootstrap Tab. But when it goes to the level 3 of nested level, drag effect is not working properly.

Also the Bootstrap Tab view on the 2nd and 3rd level, each of it's link is not loading the corresponding div view (the one with .tab-pane and reference id), but the first level is working fine. I created a click function of each links to remove the parent 'active' class which displays the links view div upon clicked but seems nothing to work.

```
var nestedList = $("ul.nested_with_switch li ul").children("li");

nestedList.click(function(){
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
})

nestedList.click(function(){
    if($(this).data('clicked') === true){
     nestedList.parents("ul li").removeClass("active");
     nestedList.find("li").removeClass("active");
    }
})
```

Here's the [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/TheSleepingEight/gVTjv/12/).

Comment: You seem to be adding two click listeners to each `nestedList` item... that's probably not what you want?

Comment: Yes, I think I messed the code.

Answer (score 0):

Start with removing what seems to be code that does nothing... replace:

```
nestedList.click(function(){
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
})

nestedList.click(function(){
    if($(this).data('clicked') === true){
     nestedList.parents("ul li").removeClass("active");
     nestedList.find("li").removeClass("active");
    }
})
```

with:

```
nestedList.click(function(){
    nestedList.parents("li").removeClass("active");
    nestedList.find("li").removeClass("active");
})
```

Next, you probably want to use `.children("li")` instead of `.find("li")`, but I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish with your code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Hamza . The drag will only take effect upon checking the Switch. When its true, the handle on each link will enable the drag effect of each links. 1st and 2nd level works fine, my concern is on the 3rd level.

Also the Bootstrap Tab which working fine on the first level, on the nested links, its corresponding view don't show up every time the children links are clicked.